# "Flow" between computers (Logitech mouse)

Tags: attack-prevention, attack-vector

Logitech (and possibly other) mice offer a feature called "**flow**": mouse can pair with uop to 3 devices (PC, handheld, ...), and can mark, copy & paste **content** (even files) **between these 3 devices** (according to the description, not bought yet).

This would make life much easier for me, since some content is always on another device, but also *expose all devices to threats on the weakest device*.

In my understanding this implies that

- [ the mouse has internal memory (hoping it does not use "external" (foreign cloud) memory) - *sorry, learnt that content seems **not** to go primarily via mouse but via network between computers*]
- the (network-forming) software has decrypted access to all content (even if the mouse uses encrypted wireless communication)
- even scarier, this risk is not limited to the said product, since a manufacturer may simply not (yet) disclose the functionality.

How would I make sure (or limit the risk) that the mouse or driver software (on the weakest device...) does not share the copied (or any other!) content with someone else (Manufacturer, or - if hacked - to anywhere)? Specific questions:

1. Is anybody aware of such attacks existing?
2. Which reasonable measures can be taken (besides standard practice like keeping software, drivers and antivirus up to date, avoid "risky" internet
   sites and software from unsecure sources)?
3. How does standard antivirus software (Kaspersky, Norton, Avira, ... - which ever you use, I am looking for experience) handle this software that establishes kind of "unusual" network traffic? Ignore it anyway, scare the user each day by warnings, or useful monitoring?

This question is *not* about the risks of wireless communication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. For existing known vulnerabilities look [here](https://www.cvedetails.com/vendor/944/?q=logitech)
2. From Logitech site:

> Logitech Flow requires computers that can connect to each other over a local network

So Logitech software is the app you need to trust.

Make sure to connect the mouse to the most secure workstation, because this pc will be the server for all the rest. If it gets compromised - an (very advanced) hacker has a potential access to the other clients.

3. This traffic is not exactly 'unusual', dropbox for example is much more unusual than that. If the traffic is encrypted - most of the antivirus will not inspect that at all. By definition Antivirus should care about app activity inside the pc, not about network traffic, that inspection should be done by firewalls. Only after you "copy" a file into a pc - an antivirus on active mode should check the files you copied.

P.S. I didn't check it by myself - but if you will try to use this app on OSX while the mac is used as client - I'm pretty sure you won't be able to approve privileged messages.

Comment: In other words - the content is not copy-pasted via mouse memory, but the computers establish a network across all platforms, with one of them chosen as server?
Seems to make sense to chose the stronegst one (partial answer to Q 2). Anybody some idea on Q 1 and 3?

Comment: See my edited answer